# Why doesn't this comparison work?

Tags: php, javascript, programming-languages

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is JavaScript's Math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-javascripts-math-broken)

`If(0.3-0.2==0.2-0.1)` most of programming language showing result `false`.So I want to know which Language Support this statement `true` and why most of language shows `false`.

Tested in `Javascript` and `PHP`.  Why does this happen?

Comment: At first glance this sounds like a contentious question, however rewording to expose the real meat makes it sound less so (I believe the real meat deals with using a floating point approximation rather than a rational representation).  I have edited appropriately.

Comment: @prashanth possible, but the OP also asks which langues support this by default.  Though I agree there is a definitely striking resemblance ..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason that this happens is not to do necessarily with a language, *per se*, but an implementation.  The answer to this question is that when you write `If(0.3-0.2==0.2-0.1)`, you are thinking that the operations performed are in the rationals, this is false, they are indeed in floating point arithmetic.  Indeed, within floating point arithmetic, this *is* false!  So the answer is: any language which defaults to interpreting constants in an arbitrarily precise arithmetic.  (For example, if these had been written in Haskell using a [Rational](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#t%3aRational) number, then the test would have "worked.")  For completeness: the [Racket](http://racket-lang.org) language does this.